# Iterate over numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following array:

```
x = np.array([[0,2,4,5,5.5,6,7],[4,5,6,7,2,3,4]])
```

Based on that array I need to create another array that skip the rows unit the value in the first column is >5.

So the result should like like this:

```
([[5.5,6,7],[2,3,4]])
```

Any hints for a simple (and fast) method for that problem?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a [boolean array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) as index for filtering.

```
>>> x[:, x[0] > 5]
array([[ 5.5,  6. ,  7. ],
       [ 2. ,  3. ,  4. ]])
```

- `x[0]` selects the first row
- `x[0] > 5` creates an array of boolean, checking whether an element is > 5 or not. (This is `[False, False, False, False, True, True, True]`.)
- When we write `some_array[boolean_array]`, we  only keep the elements in `some_array` which the corresponding value in `boolean_array` is True. For instance,

  ```
  >>> numpy.array([2, 4, 6, 8])[numpy.array([True, False, False, True])]
  array([2, 8])
  ```
- Since we are going to select columns, the boolean array `x[0] > 5` should be placed in the second axis. We select the whole first axis with `:`. Thus the final expression is `x[:, x[0] > 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Or the enumerate function:

```
    res = []
    for i, _ in enumerate(x):
    res.append([])
    for j, val in enumerate(x[i]):
        if j > 5:
            res[i].append(val)
```